# :lvimgrep with one match per file

Tags: vimgrep

Is there a way to use `:lvimgrep` and to limit the results to one match per file, so that each file with a match only appears once in the location list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [help](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#:vimgrep) you can use `:1lvimgrep pattern` to have only a single match per file added to the quickfix list.
I have never tried that however and so I am not sure how well that works.

**Update**
Okay, I have apparently misunderstood the problem as mentioned in the comments.

So there does not seem to exist an easy way to do what you want. That leaves us with those alternatives:

- Use an external grep like tool

`grep` supports the `-l` [flag](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#General-Output-Control), which makes it stop on the first match per file. Same is true for [git-grep](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep#git-grep--l). This has the additional advantage that it might be a lot faster and you  can use standard perl like regexps as this is often a complaint for many users about the [leaning toothpick syndrom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome). And you can use it with a custom [`:help 'grepprg'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27grepprg%27) so the result will be available in the quickfixlist.
However this might be a problem, if you depend on vim like regular expressions, as this will become impossible.

- Filter the vimgrep result

Use the [getloclist()](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getloclist()) or [getqflist()](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getqflist()) functions to post-process the result from `lvimgrep` and only get a single match per file. However, this has the disadvantage, that `vimgrep` still processes the complete file (so has no performance benefit if it would stop on the first match) and you will also add additional costs to filter the result.

Something like this should work:

```
function! FilterLocList()
  let a=getloclist(0)
  let file={}
  let result=[]
  for entry in a
    if !has_key(file, entry.bufnr)
      call add(result, entry)
      let file[entry.bufnr]=1
    endif
  endfor
  if !empty(result)
    call setloclist(0, result, 'r')
  endif
endfu

com! -nargs=0 FilterLocList :call FilterLocList()
```

So after doing a `:lvimgrep` command, you call `:FilterLocList` and the location list for the current window will only contain the first match.

- Make use of `:lnf` and `:lpf` commands

You can use the [`:help :lnf`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Alnf) and [`:help :lpf`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Alpf)

You simply do not care, how many entries the location list has and you jump directly to the next file in the location list using the `:lnf` command. You can jump to the previous file using the `:lpf` command. Similar commands exist for the quickfix list (`:cnf` and `:cpf`)
- Use a custom command

Another alternative would be to create a custom command, that does what you want. Something like this:

```
function! LVimgrepOnce(pattern, argspat)
  let args=glob(a:argspat, 1, 1)
  if empty(args)
    echo "No matching files found"
    return
  endif
  " clear location list
  lexpr []
  for file in args
    try
      exe "1lvimgrepadd /". a:pattern. '/j' file
    catch
    endtry
  endfor
  lopen
  let w:quickfix_title='vimgrep '. a:pattern. ' '. a:argspat
endfu

:com! -nargs=+ Lvimgrep :call LVimgrepOnce(<f-args>)
```

This will call a simple `:1vimgrepadd` command for each file specified and gather the result in the quickfix list (or more specifically in the location list).

Comment: From the help: `When a number is put before the command this is used as the maximum number of matches to find.` It gives only the first match of all matches in all files, not the first match in each file. Just tested it.

Comment: ah sorry, I totally misunderstood that then. You could probably script around that like this: `:1lvimgrep /pattern/ file1 | 1lvimgrep /pattern/ file2 | ...` (do that for all files)

Comment: There are roughly 200 files I want to make the search in, all in the same directory. Could this be easily scripted? Currently what I do is to cd into the directory and do `:lv /pattern/ *`, but as mentioned I want to avoid multiple matches from the same file.

Comment: @Andreas mentioned workarounds and scripts

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I used the filter alternative so it solves my problem. It would be much quicker to use the external `grep` though. However, when I `set grepprg=grep\ -lHn` and then do `:lgrep pattern files`, the results polulate the location list but I cannot jump from the list to the hits in files.